# Mac address filtering radius server

Tags: mac-osx-server, radius, mac-address

I would like to use the radius server on mac os x server (10.6.8) to allow users to access wireless. However the restriction i would like to use is Mac address filtering.

Is this possible? how can i do this if it is?

Answer (score 3):

It is not supported by MacOS Server in any way, but since Apple simply uses [FreeRadius](http://freeradius.org/), you could alter the configuration yourself (there are examples for this on their site).

But why would you want to do this? Mac addresses are easily spoofed, and the name based access control MacOS offers could be considered much safer.